# Neo4j graph to cypher conversion

Tags: graphs, neo4j

Is there a way or tools available to generate or retrieve cypher query from a Neo4j database ? Should we need to store cypher quries along with the graph data for regeneration ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has already been answered in [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18830686/674487). There is no need to save the queries you used to populate the database, you only need to dump the contents of the database to a file:

```
db1/neo4j-shell -path db1/data/graph.db/ -c dump > export_data.cypher
```

In order to load the database dump into another database, you just supply it to neo4j shell through the standard intput:

```
db2/bin/neo4j-shell -path db2/data/graph.db/ < export_data.cypher
```